# Merge the tags [cell] and [cells]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I think the so-questions with tag [cell](/questions/tagged/cell) (777 questions) should be merged with tag [cells](/questions/tagged/cells) (161 questions). Since plural 's' tags names seems to be a so-convention.

Comment: Shouldn't both be synonyms for [tag:table] really?

Comment: Cell seems a very common name for table though. Lots of people call them cells and not tables.